# Java Application Crash Intermittently - WHY

Tags: java, crash, centos

The Java Application is 1.8_144 running on , and the error is:

```
(java:15792): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'java' received an X Window System error.

This probably reflects a bug in the program.

The error was 'RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)'.

  (Details: serial 7783 error_code 143 request_code 139 minor_code 7)

  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;

   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.

   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

---

In addition, the OS log is:

```
[root@FlexWeightScaleTest logs]# cat /var/log/messages | grep -i 'dumping core'

Feb 25 00:27:01 FlexWeightScaleTest abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 8128 (java) of user 1001 killed by SIGTRAP - dumping core

Feb 25 00:35:52 FlexWeightScaleTest abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 11646 (java) of user 1001 killed by SIGTRAP - dumping core

Feb 25 13:14:24 FlexWeightScaleTest abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 9075 (java) of user 1001 killed by SIGTRAP - dumping core

Feb 25 13:47:59 FlexWeightScaleTest abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 15792 (java) of user 1001 killed by SIGTRAP - dumping core
```

==================================================

OS Info:

```
[root@FlexWeightScaleTest logs]# uname -r
3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
```

---

```
[root@FlexWeightScaleTest logs]# lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch

Distributor ID: CentOS

Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 

Release:    7.5.1804

Codename:   Core
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: ... and if you do, make sure to present a [mcve] with it.  We are very unlikely to be able to answer a question in this general area without one.

Comment: `To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)` did you do this? When in doubt, fully read and comprehend the error messages.

Comment: [this thread](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/149) looks related.

Comment: Not sure how to attach a debugger to dive into the detail. Still need to resolve the issue.